# Need help ... Bootstrap Button / matchMedia / removeClass

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, matchmedia

In a website I use a menu. If you call the page with the PC the menu should be fully visible. If you call the page with the mobile phone, only one button should be visible and with a click on the button the menu opens.

In the PC version everything is ok. The Menu is visible and the button hidden.

When calling with the mobile phone the button is visible. The Menu is however also folded out.

Here is the code:

```html
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-xl" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menulist">Show more ...</button>

<div id="menulist" class="collapse in">
 <div class="panel-body nav-menu-left">
  <table class="table">
   <tr><td><a href="1.php">Menu 1</a></td></tr>        
   <tr><td><a href="2.php">Menu 2</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="3.php">Menu 3</a></td></tr>

  </table>
 </div>
</div>
     
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  if (matchMedia) {
 var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 765)");
 mq.addListener(WidthChange);
 WidthChange(mq);
  }

  function WidthChange(mq) {
 if (mq.matches) {
 

   $("#menulist").removeClass("in");
 }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line

```
<div id="menulist" class="collapse in">
```

with

```
<div id="menulist" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
```